# showkey equivalent on mac os x?

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, macports

I'm debugging an emacs keyboard binding on my mac (C-/ to undo, if you're curious), and I came across a suggestion on EmacsWiki that I could use "showkey" to find the scancode. But it looks like a GNU/Linux-only kinda thing. Didn't find it on MacPorts. Anyone know of an alternative or something I'm missing?

Comment: Just noticed this old question and remembered that I did end up porting it to macports: https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/sysutils/showkey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Showkey's home page is http://catb.org/esr/showkey/.

FYI, if you're using Terminal.app, there's something of a known issue that C-/ is broken and doesn't get sent through to underlying applications. iTerm.app doesn't have that issue.

Comment: thanks, that saves me a lot of trouble trying to make it work. i'll give iTerm a whirl. wish i could have checked both answers here...

Comment: FWIW it compiled without a problem on my Mac and worked fine

Answer (score 8):

[Key Codes](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/) may be what you're looking for generally, even if you're out of luck with `C-/`.

The emacs-app port works well if you need to escape from Terminal.app

Comment: thanks. yeah, that's what i was looking for. might try durin's suggestion and try out iTerm before i give up on terminals completely. i just can't quite get used to emacs without a terminal.

Comment: Well, you can always put the terminal inside emacs.